# List - Queue(C++)

Tags: list, c++11, stl, c++17

In the following code:

```
class sample{
 private: 
  int x1;
  list <int> *x2;

 public:
  sample();   
  void samplefunc1();
  void samplefunc2();
};

void sample::sample(int n){
 x1 = n;
 x2 = new list <int> [x1]; 
}
```

I am not able to understand what happens in the constructor.

I understood that the `class sample` has a pointer to a `list <int>` as a data member, named `x2`. But in the constructor while the allocation what is happening in the code `x2 = new list <int> [x1];`.

The above code is an abridged version of the code from the following site: 
[Breadth Traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/)

Comment: it is array newing an pointer to an array of `x1` `list<int>`s

Comment: Where is the pointer x2 pointing to? Is it pointing to the base address of the list?

Comment: It is pointing to the first `list<int>` in the array of `x1` `list<int>`s :) (it's just a chunk of uninitialilsed memory)

Comment: Ohk. Thank you so much :)